# BMI[C#] Calculator featuring a regular calculator -- Issues when it comes to the main calculator (Schoolboy Error?)

Tags: c#, calculator

So I recently made a calculator as part of my A-Level computing class, and it worked fine then my teacher told me to add a BMI Calculator, which again works fine, however now the issue is the calculator does not run. Here is the code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace Calculator1
{
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Hello! Type BMI to head to the BMI Calulator");
        Console.WriteLine("If you want a calculator -- Here are your commands:");
        Console.WriteLine("TIMES - ADD - SUBTRACT - DIVIDE");
        string text = Console.ReadLine();
        if (text == "BMI")
        {
            Console.Clear();
            Console.WriteLine("Welcome to the BMI Calcualtor! Please enter your height (M)");
            string height = Console.ReadLine();
            Double height1 = Convert.ToDouble(height);
            Double height2 = height1 * height1;
            Double heightB = Convert.ToDouble(height2);
            Console.Clear();
            Console.WriteLine("Please enter your Weight(KG)");
            string weight = Console.ReadLine();
            int weight1 = Convert.ToInt32(weight);
            Double weightA = Convert.ToDouble(weight1);
            Double fbmi = weightA / heightB;
            Console.WriteLine(fbmi);
            if (fbmi < 18.5)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("UnderWeight");
                Console.ReadLine();
            }
            if (fbmi > 18.5&& fbmi < 25.0)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Normal");
                Console.ReadLine();
            }
            if (fbmi > 25.0 && fbmi < 29.9)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("OverWeight");
                Console.ReadLine();
            }
            if (fbmi > 29.9 && fbmi < 40.0)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Obese");
                Console.ReadLine();
            }
            if (fbmi > 40.1)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Extremely Obese");
                Console.ReadLine();
            }
            if (text == "TIMES")
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Enter your first number");
                string number = Console.ReadLine();
                int NumberA = Convert.ToInt32(number);
                Console.WriteLine("Enter your second number");
                string number1 = Console.ReadLine();
                int NumberB = Convert.ToInt32(number1);
                Console.WriteLine("");
                Console.WriteLine("============");
                Console.WriteLine("ANSWER");
                Console.WriteLine("============");
                Console.WriteLine(NumberA * NumberB);

                Console.ReadLine();
            }
            if (text == "ADD")
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Enter your first number");
                string number = Console.ReadLine();
                int NumberA = Convert.ToInt32(number);
                Console.WriteLine("Enter your second number");
                string number1 = Console.ReadLine();
                int NumberB = Convert.ToInt32(number1);
                Console.WriteLine("");
                Console.WriteLine("============");
                Console.WriteLine("ANSWER");
                Console.WriteLine("============");
                Console.WriteLine(NumberA + NumberB);

                Console.ReadLine();
            }
            if (text == "SUBTRACT")
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Enter your first number");
                string number = Console.ReadLine();
                int NumberA = Convert.ToInt32(number);
                Console.WriteLine("Enter your second number");
                string number1 = Console.ReadLine();
                int NumberB = Convert.ToInt32(number1);
                Console.WriteLine("");
                Console.WriteLine("============");
                Console.WriteLine("ANSWER");
                Console.WriteLine("============");
                Console.WriteLine(NumberA - NumberB);

                Console.ReadLine();
            }
            if (text == "DIVIDE")
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Enter your first number");
                string number = Console.ReadLine();
                int NumberA = Convert.ToInt32(number);
                Console.WriteLine("Enter your second number");
                string number1 = Console.ReadLine();
                int NumberB = Convert.ToInt32(number1);
                Console.WriteLine("");
                Console.WriteLine("============");
                Console.WriteLine("ANSWER");
                Console.WriteLine("============");
                Console.WriteLine(NumberA / NumberB);

                Console.ReadLine();
            }
        }
    }
}
}
```

So, any help is appreciated :)

Comment: Where is the code? :)

Comment: @Khan Sorry, first time using this! It should be there now :)

Comment: no worries.  Can you be more specific with `calculator does not run`?  Does it not compile, throw an exception, or else?

Comment: It runs perfectly fine, the BMI works perfectly, however when you try to run any of the other parts of it (I.E Times Tables etc.) it shuts down instantly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like your `{ }` are a bit out of place:

You should add a `}` after:

```
if (fbmi > 40.1)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Extremely Obese");
    Console.ReadLine();
}
```

Then remove one from the very end.

Then way it is laid out now, your other `if` statments are within the `if` statement for `BMI`.

Comment: The bane of my life in my two weeks of learning to code, the bracers just catch me out. I'll test it quickly!

Comment: Thank you Khan! Mini Lifesaver! :) +1